# SMS Broadcast Receiver onReceive() method not being called

Tags: android, xml, android-broadcastreceiver

I am building an SMS application and there is `one activity` and a `broadcast receiver`. The problem is that the `broadcast receiver` `onReceive()` method is not getting called. The `code` for the `receiver` class and `manifest` file is given below.

**Broadcast Receiver**

```java
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public AudioManager audioManager;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    boolean b=false;
    String smsBody;
    final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;

    public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

    SmsMessage smsMessage;
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"Toast Long",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        sharedPreferences = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Pritom", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
        String format = intentExtras.getString("format");
        if (intentExtras != null) {
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
            String smsMessageStr = "";
            String pass3 = sharedPreferences.getString("password", null);
            for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                    smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i], format);
                } else {
                    smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);
                }
                smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

                smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
                smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
            }
            /*if (smsBody.equals("@general" + pass3)) {
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audioManager.setRingerMode(audioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
            }*/
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS : " + smsBody + pass3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Message:", smsBody + pass3);

        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the `Toast` message just below `onReceive()` is not being displayed which indicates that the method `onReceive()` is not being called.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mytrendin.inappmessaging">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have used `Android 5.0.1` for testing my application.
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Try setting the priority android:priority="2147483647" in receivers intent-filter

Comment: @DanielNugent , I have tried that but it did not work :(

Comment: In which activity/fragment you invoked this receiver ?

Comment: @IbrahimAli , https://pastebin.com/vXxKcsUu , this is the link to my `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the higher priority `android:priority="2147483647"` in receivers `intent-filter`:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I guess there is some issue with `android 5.0`

Comment: I think you app needs run time permission for receiving SMS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970142/broadcastreceiver-sms-received-not-working-on-new-devices check this

Comment: I have done according to the answer given by you, but the problem still persists. Can you please check the code ? [link] https://pastebin.com/vXxKcsUu